# Path.FillType.INVERSE_WINDING doesn't work in HardwareAccelerated View

Tags: android, path, android-canvas, android-custom-view, hardware-acceleration

I am trying to draw a Rectangle but with INVERSE_WINDING. This works as expected in the case of `LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE`, but weirdly in case of Hardware Acceleration. The below are the results:

[image: Hardware Accelerated Result] [image: Software Accelerated Result]

**CODE:**

```
public class PathView extends View {

private final Paint mPaint;

public PathView(Context context) {
    this(context, null, 0);
}

public PathView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public PathView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    // setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null); // Toggle this!!!
    mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    final Path path = new Path();
    path.addRect(50,50,400,400, Path.Direction.CCW); // CCW or CW, same result
    path.close(); // same result even if I didn't close the path
    path.setFillType(Path.FillType.INVERSE_WINDING);
    canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
}
}
```

Why is Android behaving this way? I read the documentation on [What can't be done in Hardware Acceleration](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#unsupported), but it never mentioned anything on `Path.FillType`.

How do I get the same behavior in Hardware Acceleration as well?